# how to parse a firebase FDataSnapshot object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

my code retrieves structured data from firebase, but i was not clear how to get each value out of the firebase data object.  i did not find the answer on stackoverflow, i am posting the question & answer here for other beginners.

my firebase snapshot object value:

```
{
    "08AD8779-6EEB-4449-BC77-78A661ADA72E" =     {
        field1 = "to device id";
        field2 = "text message";
    };
    "EB841471-618C-4C52-8AA0-C20AD2C947AC" =     {
        field1 = "to device id";
        field2 = "text message";
    };
}
```

how to assign the device id (eg. "08AD8779-6EEB-4449-BC77-78A661ADA72E") and the value of 'field1' and 'field2' to NSString variables?

Comment: What language are you working in? It may also help if you share the code that you use to get the data from Firebase.

Comment: Retrieving data is covered in each SDK's guide, with examples: [web](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html), [iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html), [Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html), and [REST](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html). Did you have a problem not covered there?

Comment: Kato, i spent a lot of time on the ios SDK guide, very clear how to get the snapshot of data (the object), but did not find how to extract the value of each field inside the object.  i dug the answer from firebase example code, posted the question/answer on stackoverflow to make finding it easier for the next person.

Answer (score 7):

following is the code that worked for me:

```
-(void)readFirebaseData {
    // Read data and react to changes
    [self.myRootRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        for (FDataSnapshot* childSnap in snapshot.children) {
            NSString* otherDeviceName = childSnap.name;
            NSLog(@"otherDeviceName -> %@", childSnap.name);
            NSLog(@"otherDeviceField1 -> %@", childSnap.value[@"field1"]);
            NSLog(@"otherDeviceField2 -> %@", childSnap.value[@"field2"]);
        }     
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hello, any idea on how to achieve this in swift ?

Comment: hi Rom_j, i do not know how to do this in swift (i have not started learning swift yet).

Comment: This answer is outdated

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.There is no name property on FDataSnashot so assumed it as value with key name.

```
        for childSnap in  snapshot.children.allObjects as [FDataSnapshot]{
            let otherDeviceName = childSnap.value["name"] as NSString
            println("otherDeviceName -> \(otherDeviceName)");
            let field1 = childSnap.value["field1"]
            let field2 = childSnap.value["field2"]
            println("otherDeviceField1 -> \(field1)");
            println("otherDeviceField2 -> \(field2)");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are okay, but if someone wants to have a clean structure with error recognition: [SnapshotParser](https://github.com/Appyx/SnapshotParser)

The following code would be necessary to get a fully working swift representation:

```
func main(){
    let devices=SnapshotParser().parseAsList(snap: Snapshot, type: Device.self)
}

class Device: ParsableSnapshot {
    var id: String?
    var field1:String?=nil
    var field2:String?=nil

    required init(){}

    func bindProperties(binder: SnapshotParser.Binder) {
        binder.bindField(name: "id", field: &id)
        binder.bindField(name: "field1", field: &field1)
        binder.bindField(name: "field2", field: &field2)
    }
}
```